# How to Emulate Default Navigation Menu Behaviour in a Custom Theme?

Tags: theme-development, menus, theme-twenty-fourteen

I'm trying my hand at developing a custom theme, and I've got navigation menus working (with the help of [this walker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker), but only if they're explicitly defined in the menu settings.

The default themes (twentyfourteen, twentythirteen) seem to be able to create a default menu solely from the existing pages hierarchy, without needing to create a separate menu structure. I've had a look around the source for the twentyfourteen theme, but as far as I can tell, the menu is generated with a standard `wp_nav_menu` call. I don't see anything that accounts for how it loads a menu when none are defined.

Does anyone know how I can automatically populate my menus as the default themes do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) arguments set the `fallback_cb` argument to [`wp_page_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu), which outputs a list of pages if your menu doesn't exist. If your menu doesn't behave this way, that argument has been overridden in some way, either from being explicitly set in the `wp_nav_menu` call, or perhaps via the [`wp_nav_menu_args`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_nav_menu_args) filter.

Comment: Thanks, the custom walker I was using seems to override the fallback default.